# Group project programming in php, sql, js etc

Tags: php, svn, ide

I'm developing a website using php, html, mysql, js etc... with 3 friends, I need an application or a site that allows us to develop the website together.
I mean that I'm finding a way according to which each person can make some changes to the files and there must be a way to compare the changes and let each one accept them in order to know every modification we make and guarantee project consistency.

Is it related to SVN system?

Is there anything I can use?
Thanks

Comment: It is related with Version Control. SVN is one tool. There are also git, mercurial etc etc.

Comment: Bitbucket is your friend ;)

Comment: how does bitbucket work? when doing `git commit -m "First commit. Adding a README` I get error: `*** Please tell me who you are.
Run git config --global user.email "you@example.com" git config --global user.name "Your Name"`